# How I can iterate over a binary tree without using pointers or references?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, traversal

One can iterate over a list without using pointers or references.
In some cases this removes the need for actually having the list.
Consider the following code,

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
 printf("%i ", i % 2);
```

It directly outputs the list 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 without actually storing the list in memory.

How can one do a similar thing with binary trees?

Please show a way to implement tree_iterator, new_root_tree_iterator and, traverse_tree_iterator for the following code where upper_boundary_of_tree is something analogous to the number 10 in the list example and that I don't know how to define.

People have been having trouble with what I mean by upper_boundary_of_tree. The upper boundary of the tree would not be represented by the number 10. I don't know how to represent some upper boundary of a tree. This is part of the question. The upper boundary of the tree is similar to how the number 10 is used in the list code above, as in it does the same function, marking where to stop iterating but, it is very definitely not the same thing.

If you need to you can have a free_tree_iterator function as well.

```
tree_iterator i = new_root_tree_iterator();
while (traverse_tree_iterator(&i, upper_boundary_of_tree))
 foobar(i);
```

This has been bothering me for a while.

Comment: Have you tried solving this yourself? Write a tree iterator that uses pointers or references.

Comment: A function that prints numbers into a text stream is displaying a sequence, It is not creating a list. An abstract sequence is not the same thing as a list.

Comment: If you want to work with lists that are not stored in memory, you want lazy lists. It's possible for a lazy list to produce an indefinite number of items, and at the same be processed by some function which consumes the list, and it all happens in constant memory. (Because the consumer is marching down the list, losing the reference to the front, which is garbage collected.)  This still involves pointers, though.

Comment: It's not the laziness exactly, it's simply the functional representation of the tree, I want. One can represent a stream of things, x, by the type (Natural -> x). I want I similar thing for infinite trees, a type, Index, where (Index -> x) is the same as an infinite binary tree of x.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot iterate over non-existing data. What is shown in the first example is a loop that is printing either 0 or 1 ten times. The idea of iterating through the array (or any other data structure) is to handle each element in some sort of way, e.g calculate sum of array elements.

In other words, first example is emulating iteration over array of 10 elements, which are zeros and ones, one following another. So, on each iteration you are predicting the value based on its index.

If you want to calculate index of the children nodes in a binary tree, you can use [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) distribution formula: 2n+1 and 2n+2, would calculate index of left and right nodes respectively, where n is a 0-based index. Based on the index calculated, you can emulate node's value.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a good representation of an index of a tree data structure but, how can one represent the upper bound of the list which gives when to stop iterating?

Comment: Since it's a binary tree, 2 in power of n-elements - 1 will give you a maximum number of elements in a n-level tree: 2^n-1

Comment: No that's not what I meant. I need a skeleton of a tree type. Some representation of a tree of unit type elements.

Comment: What makes a tree? A relation between its nodes. Each node can have children. This is the definition of a tree type. You first must define what you are after, the type construction or emulation of traversing.

Comment: I was trying to explain what I needed for the upper bound type and, that I had also figured it out. I needed a type struct TREE_BOUNDARY; typedef tree_boundary TREE_BOUNDARY; typedef struct { tree_boundary * left; tree_boundary * right; } tree_boundary;

Answer (score 0):

To print the notation for a tree structure without constructing a tree, analogously to the way you print a sequence instead of constructing a list, you first have to decide what your notation will look like.

Can you write down an example?

For instance, a Lisp-like notation?

((1 2) (3 4)) ;; that's a tree

Also, given an upper bound of 10, meaning there will be ten numbered leaf nodes, which of the many possible binary trees are you supposed to print?

A straight list is a degenerate binary tree, so actually your simple for loop basically satisfies the homework problem.

Comment: I want a notation where I have a list of indexes and elements of the tree. For example, [(i0, 'a'), (i1, 'b'), (i2, 'c')] where i0, i1 and, i2 are things I'm having trouble coming up with the right notation for.